# Item modal selection options - multiple selection + quantity

Tags: modal-windows, drop-down-list, many-options, product-details

[image: Item modal with multiple selection & quantity]

As you can see above I have the situation of an item modal where there are different variations, from which I can select different quantities or none.
Currently there is a checkbox selection, and a quantity selection. If I select the checkbox, I have to add the quantity as well with a dropdown (quantities values are 10+ on average). If I select a quantity, the checkbox is automatically applied.

What is the best way to set up the UI? Should the checkbox option be removed completely, and have users just select the quantity? Should the quantity option be removed initially, and have it appear only when checkbox is selected?

Opinions/advice would be appreciated here. Thanks!

Comment: I have same case with yours, do you have any other improvement for this case?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the checkboxes are necesserary here. Just use a Steper to add qty. If the user add one or more items, so it's clear that these item is selected.
Steper is better than dropdown for numeric values[image]

Comment: In general I agree, however on this case the average selected quantity is around 20, so steper feels a bit off. Definitely agree on removing checkboxes tho